# Unable to install MOSAIC on windows or Mac OS

Tags: python, anaconda, mosaic

I am trying to download and run some software I need to look at for my bachelor assignment.
However, the instructions on the website (https://pages.nist.gov/mosaic/html/doc/InstallWindows.html#id19) make me use my terminal. I have no experience using the terminal and am having issues.

The instructions made me install anaconda_ .

When installing the dependencies I found that even after adding the installation source (conda-forge) some dependencies are not found. I tried to install from a downloaded source distribution.

I put the unpacked zip in my MOSAIC folder but I am now getting an error when running the line:

```sh
$ python setup.py mosaic_deps
```

This results in:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
```

I have no idea how to fix this problem. If someone could have a look at it and explain that would really help me out.

Comment: _When installing the dependencies I found that [...] some dependencies are not found. I tried to install [...]_ Can you provide some more information on that?

Comment: Is that the entire error message? You will have to provide the complete error message, as well as what version of Python you are using, how you installed anaconda, etc.